# Question on multiple checkboxes launching code

Tags: vba, userform

I have a user form and a frame with 35 checkboxes in it, numbered 1 to 35.  They represent 35 Named Ranges.  I test to see if any of the name ranges are not set, if set correctly the checkbox value is set to TRUE.

I found some code that would allow me to trigger a sub if one of the checkboxes is clicked.  That code seems to work, but my check code above also triggers the checkbox events, which I do not want.  I only want the sub to run when the checkbox is clicked with the mouse?  I can post the code I'm using, but though I'd first ask the question to see if what I would like to do is possible.

Thanks,
Jim

```
Code in class module:
Public WithEvents ChkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Sub AssignClicks(ctrl As Control)
    Set ChkBox = ctrl
End Sub

Public Sub chkBox_Click()
If chkBoxProcess = "Y" Then
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ChkBox.Name).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    'MsgBox ("check box number = " & ChkBox.Name & " " & ChkBox.Value)
'    Else
    End If
End Sub


Code in Forms:

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim SheetCount, i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
'Public SheetName, SheetName2, StartOldNewTimeA, OldNewTimeAdd As String

'Initialize the form frmChgNameRng
'Set array values of the day options
'Set array values for 12:00 timeframes
'Set array values for 12:30 timeframes
'Set colors used in Checkboxes
'Set array for Checkboxes (boxes are numbered accross the page, 1 corressponds to Mon_1200/Mon_1230, 8 corresponds to Mon_200/Mon_230, etc.)
'Formulas are placed in the time cells on the left of the page, the macro will add the appropriate value into the Mon_1200 time slot and all other cells update off that cell
chkBoxProcess = "N"

Dim ChkBoxes As cls_ChkBox
Dim ctrl As Control

Set colTickBoxes = New Collection

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        Set ChkBoxes = New cls_ChkBox
        ChkBoxes.AssignClicks ctrl
        colTickBoxes.Add ChkBoxes
    End If
Next ctrl
'..... lots of code for Range Name Checks, etc.
End Sub
```

Comment: You could probably use `Application.EnableEvents = False`?

Comment: @dwirony unless I'm mistaken, `Application.EnableEvents` has no bearing on MSForms controls.

Comment: *I can post the code I'm using* - that's generally a very very good idea. Otherwise we can only guesstimate what you're doing from the blurry descriptions. Please read [mcve], and [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon You are right :) I thought it might work, just tried to no avail with form controls and ActiveX....

Comment: What does "if any of the name ranges are not set" means?

Comment: Public WithEvents ChkBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Sub AssignClicks(ctrl As Control)
    Set ChkBox = ctrl
End Sub

Public Sub chkBox_Click()
If chkBoxProcess = "Y" Then
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(ChkBox.Name).Value = Format(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    'MsgBox ("check box number = " & ChkBox.Name & " " & ChkBox.Value)
'    Else
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I check to see if Range Names are set to an appropriate value, e.g, cell B7 would be named Mon_1200 (there are 2 time frames, 1200, 200, 400, 600, 800 and 7 days, Mon, Tue, etc), cell B8 would be set to Mon_200, etc. In order for the spreadsheet to function properly all the name ranges must be set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is conflating *control state* with *model data*, and so the only way to tell it "named range 32 is ON", or "named range 13 is OFF", is to alter a checkbox' state, which fires that control's `Change` event.

There's no way around that, it's just how controls work: they fire a `Change` event whenever their value changes, regardless of how that's done.

Instead of having controls' state *be* the data, make the controls' state *alter* the data.

This requires conceptualizing this data, first: looks like you need to associate a number/index to some Boolean value. An array can do this.

```
Private namedRangeStates(1 To 35) As Boolean
```

Note that depending on what you're doing, initializing the state should be feasible by iterating the workbook's `Names` collection in the `UserForm_Initialize` handler. Or better, the form could expose a method that takes an array of Boolean values, and copies that state into `namedRangeStates`.

Now, when a checkbox is modified, make it alter the state:

```
Private Sub Checkbox31_Change()
    namedRangeStates(31) = Checkbox31.Value
End Sub
```

Your form can expose that state as a property:

```
Public Property Get NamedRangeState(ByVal index As Long) As Boolean
    NamedRangeState = namedRangeStates(index)
End Property

Public Property Let NamedRangeState(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Boolean)
    namedRangeStates(index) = value
End Property
```

And now you can modify the enapsulated state independently of the combobox values.

Comment: Mathieu, thank you for your suggestions.  I think I got most of it now, but not with the Property Get .. sub.  I ended up adding a click sub with some If then statements that provide the functionality I needed.  When I get some more time to invest in this little project I'll see if I can do it as you suggest.